# set dataSource for KendoUI multiselect manually in ASP.Net WebForms

Tags: asp.net, kendo-ui, multi-select, kendo-multiselect

I have two kendoUI multiSElect placed in two different UpdatePanel in my asp.net page ,
I want to update datasource for each of them after clicking a button on the other one.
I initialized KendoMultiselect in document.Ready like this:

```
  var multiselect = $("#MS1").kendoMultiSelect({
      change: function () { //some code },
      dataBound: function () { //some code},
      dataSource: ds1,
      dataTextField: "text",
      dataValueField: "value"
      ....
      });
```

similar for Second kendoUIMultiselect.

when I click on the first UPL button, how can I update the second MultiSelect after PostBack?

### thanks in advanced for any help.

EDITED:
I added this Code in a function called after each update

```
function UpdateDataSource() {
        var tg = $('#<%=hfTagsEdit.ClientID %>').val();

        var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            data: [tg]
        });
        var mt = $("#tagsEdit").data("kendoMultiSelect");
        mt.setDataSource(dataSource);
 }
```

hfTagsEdit can be changed each time after Ajax UpdatePanel refreshing.
the problem is :  tg= [{text:"k",value:"k"}] and adding Undefined to KendoMultiSelect, I want it to add "K" in Multiselect